# Custom DependencyProperty having the type of a model and automatic creation of ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I have a custom DP (`DependencyProperty`) for a Model. I mean the type of the DP is the same as the type of the model.

If I set a Model to the DP, as long as the view can use the Model properties, everything is fine.

Now I came to a point where I need to introduce a ViewModel and do not want to change the type of the DP. The ViewModel shall be a hidden implementation detail for users of the View. Users of the View shall bind the Model and not a ViewModel. I have done that in many places by registering a PropertyChangedEvent (on DP registration) and setting the `DataContext` of the inner controls directly inside the event handler.

As this seems to me to be common operation to do, I think I am doing it in a lame way. Is there a more streamlined, elegant way to create the ViewModel when the DP bound Model changes and bind it in the View?

Comment: I don't think this is the common way MVVM works. Your's view's DataContext is meant to be the ViewModel and not the Model. What you've basically done is make your Model a ViewModel and then now your having another ViewModel? Just set the View's datacontext to it's ViewModel and expose the Model as a Property in the VM and if the Model implements INPC. Changes should get propagated to the View

Comment: As long as the Models are so simple that the VM are a huge overhead, it's not forbidden to bind to Models directly. But the point of my question is that the DP should not be a ViewModel and I really would like to bind a custom Model to it and let the View create the ViewModel and perform its bindings to the VM without having to write  lots of code. Maybe use a converter that converts the DP to a ViewModel? Maybe you're right and should turn the DP to be ViewModels... I do not know the best practices in this case.

Comment: I dont get why a VM is a huge Overhead. It gives a clear seperation of concern and acts as the bridge in M -> V. It doesnt matter if you have a converter since you can only have 1 DataContext and whatever ends up creating your VM would need to set the View's DataContext as so, but your having your Model as the View's DataContext. Unless you break that your not going to get what you require. You can ofc Create the VM as a Property in the Model and thus have your bindings from the View access it through the Model but that is such a mess and I wouldn't call that MVVM at all anymore.

Comment: In MVVM people prefer to have 1 VM per View, if you have no View controlling Logic, then keep the VM simple and just expose the Model as a property. You thus save having an extra DP in your View's and expanding your project gets streamlined when you decide to have View controlling logic like what you have run to right now

Comment: Thanks Viv, so DPs shall never be used for storing Models or VievModels, just settings to control the View. Is my understanding correct now? I thought that having a typed DP for the model is a good idea and wanted to create the VM "on the fly" I am not renitent to use VM, I just miss how to do it in this context.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I've just added an answer showing the structure I generally follow. It's too long to fit in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you mentioned in your comment's you do not need a DP to hold the Model or the ViewModel and normally you try to avoid coding into such situations unless some edge case demands it for whatever reason. Use DP's to extend a Control / View's functionality and not to store either Model or ViewModel.

This is the Logic I generally follow:

Imagine we have a **Model**: MyModel, **Views**: ParentView, Child1View, Child2View

- Have 1 VM per View. Thus we have 3 VM's ParentViewModel, Child1ViewModel, ...
- Have the Parent View in it's Resources declare `DataTemplate` with `DataType` of child `ViewModel`'s and the `Content` of the `DataTemplate` it's corresponding Child View.

Example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Child1ViewModel}">
  <local:Child1View />
</DataTemplate>
```

- Now in the ParentView set it's `DataContext` as `local:ParentViewModel`
- In ParentViewModel create a Property(CurrentViewModel) to hold the ChildModels. I use MVVM Light and thus my property type is normally `ViewModelBase` which all my ViewModels are of.
- In ParentView bind the ContentControl's Content accordingly to this property

Example:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

Now by just switching this property in the ParentViewModel your `ContentControl` gets updated accordingly and you do not have the need to add any DP's at all.

Now if MyModel implements INPC itself which in MVVM Light can be achieved by making your Models inherit from `ObservableObject`(Try to not use `ViewModelBase` as a base class for Models. It's just confusing and adds clutter), You can just expose the model as a property(ModelProperty) in your ViewModel's

Thus in each corresponding View to bind to a Model directly all you'd be doing is something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ModelProperty.TextBlockText}" />
```

Now because the Model implements INPC, changes will automatically get reflected in the View if made in the Model.

That's it, sit back and watch your app evolve when functionality gets added on in corresponding sections henceforth

Do note that on top of this if you use something like Unity you get Dependency injection and sorts which further makes life a whole lot easier when your app is growing

Comment: Thank you for detailing the methods you are using. I can benefit a lot from this experience. I need to read more about MVVM, I had a pragmatic approach in learning it until now. I feel I am stuck at a level that is good enough to start reading more theory and information about the topic to get better. My methods are experimental and crappy, that's what I realize now.