# Switching views on MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, view

i have 4 view models(BaseViewModel, MainViewModel and two that are displayed for a different view: ViewModelMainPage, ViewModelWorkPage), and 1 view. I want to apply different views on a single window. So far i have created 2 datatemplates in window.resources (each for their own viewmodel). I have two buttons on a grid column 0 to switch between them, where in grid column 1 there would be displayed the selected datatemplate. From here on I dont know what to do. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is A datatemplateselctor. Look at the MSDN link for an example on how to use the selector.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can just extend your concept of having `DataTemplate`'s for Child Views declared in your Parent View.

A working example doing something **very** similar to what your doing can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views) (Try the Project "TwoViews" in the downloaded sample). Download the source and read through the article.

You can also maybe have a read through [This SO Question's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056927/custom-dependencyproperty-having-the-type-of-a-model-and-automatic-creation-of-v/16061114#comment22926780_16061114) to see how it extends when Model's come into play.

[This Codeplex sample](http://apuntanotas.codeplex.com/) is  pretty good for beginners in MVVM as well.

Comment: yeah thanks, but i have already figured it out. the solution was to create a usercontrol for each datatemplate, and then for switching between them i used an instance of the usercontrol viewmodel in the main viewmodel. In XAML i created a ContentControl and used binding on it with that instance.

Comment: Which is exactly what all the links in the answer suggest as well lol